# ways to solve optimization problem with cartesian product and restrictions in a production line

Tags: python, scheduling, cartesian-product, discrete-optimization

I'm new to this kind of problem and I'm having a lot of difficulty in understanding how to solve this problem: let's suppose we have 3 types of objects to produce in a production line (A, B, C), I know the processing time of each onject on the production line (Pa, Pb, Pc).

the problem is quite simple I think, I want to find the optimal scheduling of daily production respecting the following constraints:

- I have to stay within the range of 8 working hours
- each product has a minimum daily production to be respected.

so, to give an example, let's say that I have to produce a **minimum** of:

- 3 type A products
- 2 type B products
- 1 type C product

*in 8 hours*

I would like to obtain an algorithm whose output for example is:

***in 8 hours the sequence of products you have to make respecting the constraints is AABBBCAAC***.

now, I tried to do it with a simple Cartesian product using itertools of Python, trying to filter the solution, but for my problem the algorithm is too expensive at a computational level because I have a very high daily production of products.

I also tried to use search algorithms, but I don't quite understand how to embed constraints.

finally, I tried to formulate the problem with Mixed Integer Programming, but I don't know if there is something faster.

Can you tell me a smarter and more effective way to solve the problem?
If you can give me some examples to understand better, I would be grateful.

Thank you

Comment: This is similar to the Knapsack problem with constraints on the weight of the knapsack, and the solution is done using Dynamic Programming.  Search for Knapsack Dynamic Programming problem you will get lots of solutions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.